# How can I add an app.config or web.config file in Visual Studio Web 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

This has been frustrating me for the past hour. My project is like

```
MySolution
    MyTestProject
      ClassThatTestsMyRepository.cs
    MyMVCProject
      App_Data
      App_Start
      Controllers
      .
      .
```

and the root of my problem is that my tests in the other project aren't working because they're trying to access a connection string that is in the MVC project itself. My plan was to add an app.config file and then reference the web.config in the MVC project. However, when I go to Add -> New Item there are no configuration files in Installed or Online.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E4XS.png)

The only reason there's a web config in my MVC project is because it was built from a template that added it. Any ideas how I can add it to my test project if I can't add it through stupid VS Web 2013?

Answer (score 1):

It is just an XML file called "web.config" placed at the root of your MVC project.
Then you can just create a new text file and rename it.
if the project is a console app or a test project, the name is App.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" connectionString="xxxx" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click your project and select `Add New Item...`
2. Look for a template called `Application Configuration File` for local apps or it will be under `Web Configuration File` for ASP.NET projects.
3. Choose the default name and press `Add`

[image: Add app.config]

[Relevant Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/k8x4ket8(v=vs.100))